# Cannot view/access attribute data from KML file in QGIS

Tags: attributes, gis, kml, shapefile, qgis

Using QGIS, when I convert a SHP file with several columns of attribute data into a KML for use in a Google Environment (e.g. Google Earth, Fusion Tables, Google Maps), I'm not able to view the attribute data following the conversion (while still using QGIS) — all I can see are two columns headers "Name" and "Description" with no cell values. Yet, if I take that same KML and load it into Google Fusion Tables, for example, suddenly all the attributes from the original SHP files are visible.

Is there a way to view the attributes of a KML while in QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough reputation to put this in a comment, thats why I give you the hit here...
Think, same problem is discussed here:[Not Importing ExtendedData from KML](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/110015/13507) and solution comes with gdal-2.0.2-4